# Edits are not getting counted

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, edits

If I go to the suggestion tab and click on an approved edit it will give me this:

> Peter Haddad had 397 edit suggestions approved, and 106 edit suggestions rejected

but in the activity it says I have 325 posts edited.

I know it takes time to update but it's been like this for a week maybe? I'm not sure if I should do more edits or not?

Comment: Tag only edits don't count towards the number shown under activity. I believe that multiple edits to a single post also only count once. So that's going to be what your difference is.

Comment: @JonClements, I was actually awarded double points for editing a post twice [check my rep histroy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6696657/mattr?tab=reputation). I had noticed i did an incomplete edit, I went back, and was awarded it twice. Will this small mishap be cleaned up?

Comment: @MattR having +2 rep is per successful suggested edit. That's independent from the number of posts considered edited. So you could edit one post five times, get the +10 rep but it's counted as 1 post edited.

Comment: @JonClements, gotcha! thank you for the clarification on that

Comment: Suggested edits is a different count from posts edited. You could have made multiple suggestions for a single post. You could have made a suggestion that only touched the tags or the title; not touching the post *body* doesn't count as a post edit. Etc. The counts are **not expected to match**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are conflating *two different metrics*.

- *Suggested edits* counts how many edit suggestions you have made
- *Posts edited* counts how many post bodies you have made at least one edit to.

There is an overlap between the two, but note that the latter counts *posts*, not the number of edits made to them. You could have edited the same post 10 times, that's still a single post you edited.

Also, suggested edits do not necessarily change the post. If you only touch the tags, the post itself was not edited.

So it is entirely normal and expected that the two numbers *don't match*. They usually won't.